# R orderbook package, creating an empty orderbook object

Tags: r, object

In the orderbook package doc, `orderbook` allows to [creating an object of class orderbook](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/orderbook/docs/orderbook). Some lines later, the same doc says that

> If you want to create an empty orderbook, just specify the file (see example).

Unfortunately, there is no example of that and it always seems to require a file as input. Any idea?

Comment: Check the edit I just made to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code for that function, the documentation is wrong.  It requires a file that already exists.  Just type `orderbook` at the prompt and you'll see the code involved:

```
obfile <- file(file, open = "r")
```

If you look at `?file` you'll see what they are trying to do.  Without a valid file, this will fail.

EDIT: by playing around I see the package author's intent.  Do this:

```
filename <- system.file("extdata", "sample.txt",
                        package = "orderbook")
ob <- orderbook(file = filename)
```

as noted in the documentation.  If you then do `str(ob)` you'll see it is empty of any actual data, ready for you to insert your data.

Comment: I thought so but I wanted to make sure that I didn't miss anything else. Too bad that this package doesn't even live up to its documentation. It seems to be abandoned since a long time anyway.

Comment: I really don't understand the way they did it. Because if I look at `sample.txt`, it's not empty, there are about 10501 lines in it!!  EDIT: I mean, if you look at the vignette and do `ob <- read.orders(ob, 10000)`, `ob` is not so empty anymore ...

Comment: I didn't look that far.  They are using `S4` classes so they should have a "new" method, but I don't see one.  I'd proceed carefully!